# luaRedisGenericCommand() recursive call detected

Tags: recursion, lua, redis

i use `Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider` as sessionState Provider and it runs many lua scripts. but my application caught this exception:

> @user_script: 14: luaRedisGenericCommand() recursive call detected.
>   Are you doing funny stuff with Lua debug hooks?

in [redis source code](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/d680eb6dbdf2d2030cb96edfb089be1e2a775ac1/src/scripting.c) the developer said:

```
static int inuse = 0;   /* Recursive calls detection. */

/* By using Lua debug hooks it is possible to trigger a recursive call
 * to luaRedisGenericCommand(), which normally should never happen.
 * To make this function reentrant is futile and makes it slower, but
 * we should at least detect such a misuse, and abort. */
if (inuse) {
    char *recursion_warning =
        "luaRedisGenericCommand() recursive call detected. "
        "Are you doing funny stuff with Lua debug hooks?";
    redisLog(REDIS_WARNING,"%s",recursion_warning);
    luaPushError(lua,recursion_warning);
    return 1;
}
inuse++;
```

But i don't know how to detect this recursion and how to avoid this error!

Comment: Which Redis (server) version are you using?

Comment: i'm using Redis **3.0.503**.

Comment: This is an old question, but if you're still having problems with this, you should include the lua script you are using.

Comment: conversation continued here: https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/3584
and the lua scripts are here in RedisConnetionWrapper.cs: https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers/blob/master/src/RedisSessionStateProvider/RedisConnectionWrapper.cs

Answer (score 0):

Recycle the app pool and Clear the Redis Cache it will work Fine ..